# MVC core partial Ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core-mvc

The code returns readable html from a partial view but will not render to a Bootstrap modal using JQuery. The error is below, commented out are various attempt. I'm pretty sure it is something to do with the DOM but the interweb is not being very forthcoming

```
$('#frm').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("clicked");


        var url = '@Url.Action("makePayment", "accounts")';

        var model = $(this).serialize();

        //console.log(model);

        //$.post(url, model, function(res) {
        //    console.log(res);

        //    $('.payModal').modal('show');
        //    $(".payModal").html(res);
        //});
        var outcome = "";
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: model,
            //dataType: 'html',
            //contentType: html,
            //processData: true,
            //contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            //cache: false,
            success: function(data) {

                outcome = data;
                //console.log(data);
                //$(document).ready(function() {
                    $(document).find("#payModal").html(data);
                    $(document).find("#payModal").modal("show");
                //});
            }

        });

        //$("#payModal").html("<p>Hello World</p>").delay(5000);
        //$("#payModal").modal("show");


    });
```

Error -

[image]

Comment: What is the value of `data`?

Comment: Input is form data (serialized) out put is html from a partial view which is reasonable (tags closed etc)

Comment: js code must be in the nested page

Comment: Modal with unique id, so should be able to recognise the DOM. The html is being returned in Ajax but not being pushed into the #payModal div.

Comment: document.getElementById("payModal").innerHTML = result ;
 $("#payModal").html(result);
produce the same error, so probably something to do with context, but still don't understand the whole illegal reason.

Comment: `$(document).find("#payModal").html(data);` cause the error? It's difficult to find the issue from the code you provide.

Comment: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/29561 hmmm... possible JQuery/Bootstrap clash...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was caused by Bootstrap 5 and JQuery not playing nicely any more. It has taken me far too long to come to this conclusion as the error message was far from explicate.
The solution -

`$(document).on('submit', '#frm', function(e) {

```
        e.preventDefault();
        var $link = $(this);

        //alert("clicked");


        var url = '@Url.Action("makePayment", "accounts")';

        var model = $(this).serialize();

        var outcome = "";
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            //dataType: 'html',
            data: model,


            success: function(result) {


                console.log(result);

                $(".modal-body").html(result);

                var myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('payModal'),{keyboard: false});
                myModal.show();



            }

        });

        

    });`


<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" id="payModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Please Confirm</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">

                <button type="button" data-bs-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-secondary">Cancel</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">OK</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Last version of BS I worked with was 4 hence my assumption that "it couldn't be  JQuery"